# Como ler apenas uma linha de um ficheiro em c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms

Sei como ler o ficheiro todo mas como posso ler apenas uma linha

EX: ler a linha 3 apenas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo `index` da linha, exemplo:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

string linha1 = allLines[0];
string linha2 = allLines[1];
string linha3 = allLines[2];
string linha4 = allLines[3];
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado dessa forma obrigado :)

Comment: @MiureSilva se deu certo, não se esqueça de marcar como respondida. Disponha.

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que primeiro selecionar todas linhas e depois pelo index escolher qual deseja

```
var file = new StreamReader(caminhoArquivo);
string[] linhas = File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo);
var textoDesejado = linhas[2];
file.Close();
```

Note que para selecionar a linha 3 é usado o index 2 e por fim, não se esqueça de fechar o arquivo.